# Is it at all possible to use UWP APIs that require Capabilities from .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, f#, uwp

I'm trying to use Bluetooth LE from F# Interactive, to which end I hope to make a C# .NET Framework class library as a proxy ([because F# isn't being supported again](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/9110134-f-support-in-net-native-for-uwp)).

Some of the API works, but as soon as I try to get a Service, it hangs:

```
        var di = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync()).First();
        var dev = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(di.Id);
        //var service = await dev.GetGattService(Guid.Parse("..."));
        var service = await dev.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(Guid.Parse("..."));
```

Apparently [it's normal behavior for APIs to hang or return null](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2ed8563-0a3a-4479-b529-82a4ab2db8f2/why-does-rfcommdeviceservicefromidasync-return-null?forum=winappswithcsharp) without so much as an exception when the Capabilities aren't set.

I don't know if capabilities can be set from .NET Framework assemblies, and if I use a Universal assembly, it can't be referenced from .NET Framework assemblies, including F# Interactive.

As far as I know, there aren't other Bluetooth client LE libraries for .NET Framework. Is .NET being left behind, or is there a way to access UWP libraries that require Capabilities?